# How can I get table descriptions from Azure SQL Database

Tags: t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

For SQL Server, I can get table descriptions from the metadata using:

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id) as SchemaName, 
    t.name AS TableName, 
    ex.value AS Description 
FROM 
    sys.tables AS t,
    sys.extended_properties AS ex 
WHERE 
    ex.major_id = t.object_id 
    AND ex.minor_id = 0 
    AND ex.name = 'MS_Description' 
    AND ex.value IS NOT NULL
```

But that throws an exception hitting an Azure SQL Database. How can I pull it from Azure SQL Database?

The exception I am getting is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred   HResult=-2146232060
>   Message=Invalid object name 'sys.extended_properties'.   Source=.Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider   ErrorCode=-2146232060   Class=16
>   LineNumber=1   Number=208   Procedure=""
>   Server=tcp:odjidszumt.database.windows.net   State=1   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>          at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>          at net.windward.utils.ado.SqlServer.WrSqlServerDatabase.TableDesc(DbConnection
>   conn, String select) in
>   c:\vso\Jenova\team\refactoring\Engine\DotNetEngine\Kailua\net\windward\utils\ado\SqlServer\WrSqlServerDatabase.cs:line
>   465   InnerException:

I have no idea what version of Sql Database - we created a Sql Database on Azure and didn't do anything special so I'm guessing the latest.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Your query worked for me in Azure SQL. Which server version of Azure SQL are you using? Does the SQL user have access to query the Master database?

Comment: @Francois - sorry no idea what version of the DB. We just created an Azure instance. All the other metadata queries work so we do have access to the master database. It's just the table & column description queries, that both use sys.extended_properties in the select, that fail.

Answer (score 2):

Officially, according to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177541.aspx), **sys.extended_properties** view is not supported in Azure SQL Database. The error message you provided says "**Invalid object name 'sys.extended_properties'**", which proved it's not supported.
[image]

However, the weird thing is that when I run the query from SSMS and SQL Server Object Explorer against an Azure SQL Database, it works. I then go back to the portal and notice that I created a V12 SQL Server, I then tried creating a V2 SQL Server and run the query against it, get the same result "**Invalid object name 'sys.extended_properties'**", see below snapshot:
[image]

So as per above test, I think 'sys.extended_properties' is only supported in Azure SQL Server V12 database. It seems MS official article might not be updated to the lastest. I'd suggest you check which version of Azure SQL Database you've created:
[image]

You can enable V12 when creating the SQL Server as below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the Azure sys tables.  I needed a solution to set columns requiring case sensitive comparison during a meta driven etl process. NOTE: might want to convert the d.[Value] field to something meta-model ingestible.

```
/*********************************
Returns Table Column Descriptions
*********************************/
Select 
   s.[name] AS SchemaName
  ,t.[name] AS TableName
  ,c.[name] AS ColumnName
  ,d.[value] AS Desription
From sys.schemas AS s
Inner Join sys.sysobjects AS t /* Tables*/
   On t.[uid] = s.[schema_id]
Inner Join sys.syscolumns AS c
   On c.id = t.id
Inner Join sys.extended_properties AS d /*Column Description*/
   On d.major_id = t.id
  And d.minor_id = c.colid
Where d.[name] = 'MS_Description'
```